# Pandas aggregate graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
z=t.groupby("CUSAGE").aggregate({'ZDIVND':['nunique','count']})
```

I would like to plot a bar graph for "`CUSAGE`" vs `ZDIVND's` count from the above code. Any help on the above would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: `z['count'].plot(kind='bar')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think use another solution for aggregation for avoid `MultiIndex` in columns - after `groupby` specify column with list of aggregation functions:

```
t = pd.DataFrame({
        'CUSAGE':list('aaaccc'),
         'ZDIVND':[4,5,4,5,5,5]
})

print (t)
  CUSAGE  ZDIVND
0      a       4
1      a       5
2      a       4
3      c       5
4      c       5
5      c       5

z=t.groupby("CUSAGE")['ZDIVND'].agg(['nunique','count'])
print (z)
        nunique  count
CUSAGE                
a             2      3
c             1      3
```

And then:

```
#if want plot both columns together
z.plot.bar()

#if want plot only count column
z['count'].plot.bar()
```

Or use [`GroupBy.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html):

```
t.groupby("CUSAGE")['ZDIVND'].count().plot.bar()
```

Comment: thank you for the above.
I forgot to mention i need to export the chart to an excel sheets as well. Could you please add the code below to do the same.

Comment: thank you for the above. I forgot to mention i need to export the chart to an excel sheets as well. Could you please add the code below to do the same

Comment: @prdp13 - Then need something different, check [this](https://pandas-xlsxwriter-charts.readthedocs.io/)