# How to do this steps better in Pandas: count, drop columns, drop duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

This is my *newly* everyday thing where I deal with a `df` with **many** columns including these two columns: `user` and `event`. I count number of `event` for each `user`, add a new column, `count` to the original `df`. Then, I only keep `user` and `count` where there are multiple identical rows then do `drop_duplicates()` to drop the duplicates and thus obtain event `count` for each `user`. I'm sure I'm doing some redundant work.

What would be an elegant way to do such tasks.

```
df['count'] = df.groupby('user')['event'].transform('count')
df = df[['user','count']]
df = df.drop_duplicates()
plt.bar(x=df['user'], height=df['count'])
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas aggregate graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52517868/pandas-aggregate-graph)

Comment: There is some problem?

Comment: @jezrael wrong clicked. sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) for `Series` and then call [`Series.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.bar.html):

```
df.groupby('user')['event'].count().plot.bar()
```